# Why are <> ALL and NOT IN aliases of each other in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

So the [mySQL dev site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/all-subqueries.html) tells me that `<> ALL` and `NOT IN` are aliases of each other. My question is, why exactly?

Let me be more specific:

`= ALL` returns true when "the comparison (here, equality) is TRUE for ALL of the values in the column that the subquery returns", i.e., each outer query row will only satisfy `outer query = ALL (inner query)` if all rows in the inner query have the same value and that
value equals the outer query row value.
So, `outer query <> ALL (inner query)` must return true when there exists **at LEAST 1** value in the inner query different from the outer query.
But `NOT IN` would return true only if **NONE** of the rows of the inner query match the outer query row in question.

Have I got something fundamentally wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, `outer query <> ALL (inner query)` must return true when there exists **at LEAST 1** value in the inner query different from the outer query.

That's not true. Just as `value = ALL (query)` returns true when `value` is equal to every value returned by `query`; `value <> ALL (query)` returns true when `value` is different from every value returned by `query`. You are apparently thinking that `value <> ALL (query)` would mean `NOT (value = ALL (query))`, but that's not the case.

Comment: Oh right. I get it... Thanks! I thought that <> ALL was equivalent to NOT( value = ALL (query))... Though logically, shouldn't it be?

Comment: @aspiring_sarge: Well, I don't know. If you translate `<>` to English as "is different from", then it makes sense that `value <> ALL (query)` would mean "`value` is different from all values returned by `query`". On other hand, if you were to translate `<>` to English as "isn't equal to", you'd end up with the meaning you were expecting. (If you're familiar with "∀" and "¬", then this is the difference between "∀¬" and "¬∀".) Personally, I think the first reading is more logical, but I won't fault you for having expected the second one.

Comment: Ahh yes... The "∀¬" vs "¬∀" example was brilliant in describing how everything isn't exactly as it seems... Thanks :)